# Coinbase API coinbase.wallet.error.NotFoundError: APIError(id=not_found): Not found

Tags: coinbase-api

I am currently trying to use the coinbase wallet API and am having trouble, i can do some basic things like client.get_current_user() etc, but if i try to create an address or wallet i get the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 301, in create_address
response = self.post('v2', 'accounts', accountid, 'addresses', data=params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 132, in _post
return self._request('post', *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 116, in _request
return self.handleresponse(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coinbase/wallet/client.py", line 125, in handleresponse
raise build_api_error(response)
coinbase.wallet.error.NotFoundError: APIError(id=not_found): Not found

I am sure that i have all permissions allowed, so thats not the problem. Any help?
I have also asked this question on the coinbase community but have had no luck getting a response.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you've no doubt figured this out by now, I will post for anyone else potentially having this problem.

The issue is you are probably passing the ID you obtained from running `client.get_current_user()['id]` this does return an ID, but its your user ID, not your wallet ID.

Calling something like `client.get_addresses('account_id')` actually requires the wallet ID, which there will be different ones for the different currencies.

You can get your wallet account id's via `client.get_accounts()`.

Hope this helps anyone that might need it later :)

Comment: Saved me a bunch of time...